# Saving a RDD to a text file in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to do 2 things:

1. Display out the contents of the RDD splitRDD to the console.
2. Save the results to a text file.

The 3rd line of scala code below prints out the key, but I am looking for the value.

```
val emailMsg = sc.textFile(file);`
val splitRDD = emailMsg.map( line => line.split("."));
splitRDD.foreach(println);
splitRDD.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("newfile")
```

Comment: Can you please add schema of splitRDD.

Comment: Not sure of what do you mean by "The 3rd line of scala code below prints out the key". The `split` method outputs an array, whose `toString` method will not actually print any member of the array itself. If you only want to print only the second item (for example) you should do something like: `splitRDD.foreach(row => row(1))`.

Comment: why are you doing `line => line.split(".")`? Can you give sample file input and your expected print output?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am doing a split on email messages (text file) and trying to separate out the from, to, date and subject. So, I am looking words like "Subject:", and "To:" and so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that your file looks like this

```
key1.value1
key2.value2
```

And you want to print and save either *values* or *pairs* in some other format.

If you want to print and save just values you can transform `splitRDD` into just values RDD.

```
val valRDD = splitRDD.map( _( 1 ) )
valRDD.foreach( println )
```

Note that `saveAsTextFile` doesn't save the file in easy to use format so you'll probably need a simple text writer (Java `PrintWriter` will do just fine).

Example to print and save `splitRDD` in two different formats

```
import org.apache.spark._
import java.io.{ PrintWriter, File, FileOutputStream }

...

val pwText = new PrintWriter(
    new File( "emailMsgValues.txt" )
)

val pwCSV = new PrintWriter(
    new File( "emailMsgPair.csv" )
)

val emailMsg = sc.textFile( "data/emailMsg.txt" )

val splitRDD = emailMsg.map( line => line.split( '.' ) )

println( "Printing and writing values in text" )

val valRDD = splitRDD.map( _( 1 ) ).collect()

valRDD.foreach( value => {

    println( value )
    pwText.write( value + "\n" )
} )

println( "Printing and writing pairs in csv" )

splitRDD.collect().foreach( pair => {

    println( pair.mkString( "," ) )
    pwCSV.write( pair.mkString( "," ) + "\n" )

} )

pwText.close()
pwCSV.close()
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed.

Comment: Great! You can accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful. Cheers @SteveMcAffer

Comment: No problem, just follow this [accept guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and [upvote guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400).  @SteveMcAffer

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying the third line is printing is not the key. It is actually printing the Array Object, something like this

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@384efaf
[Ljava.lang.String;@5bc8b97c
[Ljava.lang.String;@18194125
[Ljava.lang.String;@364838ab
[Ljava.lang.String;@254b1df2
```

What you need to do is to convert that Array object to a Row object of spark sql. So use

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

and change the second line of your code like this

```
val splitRDD = emailMsg.map( line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(" ")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This is great!